# Bit vector implementation from a given array

Tags: c, arrays, vector, bit

I'm trying to create a bit vector set from a given array. Not sure how to start it off. For example given the array: `int rows[] = {1, 2, 5}` I need to make a function `unsigned short MakeBitVector(int values[], int nValues)` You're allowed to assume that the range for the elements in the array is 1-9. Here's what I have so far:

```
unsigned short MakeBitVector(int values[], int nValues)
{
  (55)unsigned short int set = calloc(nValues, sizeof(unsigned short));
  for(int i = 0; i < nValues; i++){
    (57)set[i] = values[i];
  }
  return set;
}
```

I keep getting warnings and errors:

bits.c:55: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

bits.c:57: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely need your `set` to be a pointer:

```
unsigned short int* set = calloc(nValues, sizeof(unsigned short));
```

And you have to change the return type of the function to pointer as well.

Edit: if you want to pack everything into one int, you can go on in a simpler way:

```
unsigned short MakeBitVector(int values[], int nValues)
{
    unsigned short int set = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nValues; i++)
        set |= 1 << values[i];
    return set;
}
```

You don't need to allocate a single int, returning the copy is just fine.

Comment: This works. but is there any way that I can allocate memory without having to change everything to a pointer.I don't want to have to change the return type to a pointer.

Comment: @Vlad: That was me -- A bit-vector is a set of values represented by a binary string (eg `{1,2,5}` is represented as `11001`}. There is no need for dynamic allocation to make one of these (if the array is known to only contain elements in the range 1-9), and this answer taken on its own will end up with the rest of the code indexing into the set by a `short` at a time, rather than by a bit at a time.

Comment: @Mankarse: I cannot guess the semantics of `values`, it might be the copy of the bit vector as well. For the bit vector, I would not stay at just one int, as this restricts the set capacity to max of 64. So the bit vector's underlying structure has to be a kind of array.

Comment: @Vlad: From the question "You're allowed to assume that the range for the elements in the array is 1-9". So restricting the capacity is not a problem.

Comment: @user: well, what is your data layout? How do you plan to process more than 64 bits in the vector? Do you plan to hold the vector in one int, or in several?

Comment: @Mankarse how'd you get that binary conversion?

Comment: @Mankarse: I didn't want the bit array to be bound by 9 :-) Well, let's better wait for OP's comment.

Comment: The function returns an unsigned short that represents a bit vector set of the values from the array. The bits in positions 1-9 of the returned result mark the set membership, the remaining bits are zeros.(this is short description of the function)

Comment: @Mankarse: thank you for the constructive downvote and for courage to discuss!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need dynamic allocation at all; `calloc` is just confusing things. Also, you will need to operate on single bits somewhere which your code isn't at present. What about this:

```
unsigned short MakeBitVector(int values[], int nValues) {
  unsigned short int set = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < nValues; i++){
    set |= 1 << values[i];
  }
  return set;
}
```

Obviously the output of this is undefined if the input contains indices >= 16, but you said that shouldn't be a problem (and you could easily extend it to 32 anyway).

Answer (score 0):

`set` isn't a pointer.  Change that to a pointer instead.  You would also need to return a pointer as well.